# Add parameters to dynamic SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, odbc

I try to implement my known `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` into my new application running with SQL Server. Since this is only possible in MySQL i wrote the following code, but get some errors, when adding parameters.

Those are the error messages:

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Die @FaeBezeichnung-Skalarvariable muss deklariert werden.

ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Die @VeraendertAm-Skalarvariable muss deklariert werden.

ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Die @mitIDref-Skalarvariable muss deklariert werden.
```

***My Code looks like this:***

**strSQL:**

```
DECLARE @faeID AS int
begin tran
    SELECT @faeID = faeID FROM mdb_Faehigkeiten WHERE kurzBez = @FaeBezeichnung 
    UPDATE mdb_Faehigkeiten WITH (serializable)
    SET VeraendertAm = @VeraendertAm
    WHERE mitIDref = @mitIDref AND faeIDref = @faeID
    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin
        INSERT mdb_Faehigkeiten (mitIDref, faeIDref, VeraendertAm)
        VALUES (@mitIDref, @faeID, @VeraendertAm)
    end
commit tran
```

**C#:**

```
OdbcConnection conn = GetConnection();
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(strSQL, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mitIDref", OdbcType.Int).Value = dgv[0, item.iRow].Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@VeraendertAm", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dgv[item.iColumn, item.iRow].Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FaeBezeichnung ", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dgv.Columns[item.iColumn].HeaderText;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch { throw; }
finally { conn.Close(); }
```

Can anyone help me with this, or is it basically not possible to implement parameters into a dynamic SQL statement?

Comment: Fix your query syntax_ `SELECT @faeID = faeID FROM mdb_Faehigkeiten WHERE kurzBez = @FaeBezeichnung`

Comment: When i add the parameter, don't they get replaced anyway? Okay, the comment above fixed the first error =) ... but the declarations are still "missing"

Comment: I had a mistake in my Syntax ... wrong table. But ***yes***, i had to `DECLARE` all the variables, they don't get replaced everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your SQL script to look like this, and change the data types that I used to the data types you are using and values:

```
DECLARE @FaeBezeichnung int = 1
DECLARE @VeraendertAm int = 2
DECLARE @mitIDref int = 3
DECLARE @faeID AS int
begin tran
    SELECT  @faeID = faeID 
    FROM mdb_Faehigkeiten 
    WHERE kurzBez = @FaeBezeichnung 
    UPDATE mdb_Faehigkeiten WITH (serializable)
    SET VeraendertAm = @VeraendertAm
    WHERE 
        mitIDref = @mitIDref AND
         faeIDref = @faeID
    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin
        INSERT mdb_Faehigkeiten (mitIDref, faeIDref, VeraendertAm)
        VALUES (@mitIDref, @faeID, @VeraendertAm)
    end
commit tran
```